# DatagridviewButtonColumn is visible to every row when click on a cell of row/column

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I have a Datagridview that has some text box columns.In this Datagridview I have added a `DataGridViewButtoncolumn` after the third column and I have set it as visible = false as shown in below code.

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn btnEllipse = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

btnEllipse.Text = "...";
btnEllipse.FillWeight = 6;
btnEllipse.MinimumWidth = 20;
btnEllipse.Width = 20;
btnEllipse.DividerWidth = 0;
//btnCompanyProperty.HeaderText = "To Company/Property";
btnEllipse.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
dgvForecast.Columns.Insert(4, btnEllipse);
dgvForecast.Columns[4].Visible = false;
dgvForecast.Columns[dgvForecast.Columns["BaseValue"].Index + 1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;

dgvForecast.Columns[dgvForecast.Columns["BaseValue"].Index + 1].Width = 20;
dgvForecast.Columns["BaseValue"].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;

dgvForecast.Columns["BaseValue"].CellTemplate.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

Now My problem is that I have to show only this button cell when i click on index 3 cell.Now 
this is showing full Button column when i click on index 3 cell as shown in below image.I only want to show selected row button cell not full Button Column.

[image]

I want that when i click on first row value cell only first row Button cell should be visible and when i click on second row value cell first row button should be invisible and current row button should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide specific cells in the `DataGridView`. There is no direct support for this in the `DataGridView`.

One way of doing this is to create custom `DataGridViewButtonColumn` to control the visibility using a custom property and override the paint method to draw a rectangle with the background color when this property is set. It is similar to that available in the msdn forum question [removehide-button-on-datagridview](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6d495e29-4569-4801-b0b1-86aae56c203d/removehide-button-on-datagridview).

Using the above custom column you could make the cell visible in `CellEnter/RowEnter` event and hide it in `CellLeave/RowLeave` event.